# Google Maps API marker loop not changing title properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've been searching stackoverflow and the rest of the web to no avail. I am a novice programmer and I'm completely stuck on this problem.

I have an array that is structured as follows:

AddressA
SuburbA 
AddressB 
SuburbB

When the following code runs, it updates the map by placing a marker, and a 10mile circle around that marker. The problem is, that when I hover my mouse over the marker, the tooltip/title is always that of SuburbB, even though the markers and circles are in the correct position.

Driving me crazy, help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 function codeAddress(){

    var arrayLength = array.length;
    var looper = 0;
    var looper2 = 1;

    while (looper < arrayLength) {

        alert("Geocode started");

        sAddress = array[looper];
            alert (looper)
            alert("Address set" + sAddress)

        sName = array[looper2];
            alert (looper2)
            alert("Name set" + sName)

        geocoder.geocode( {'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) {

            alert("Make marker");

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                map.setCenter (results[0].geometry.location);

                var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    title: sName,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map,
                    radius: 16093,    // 10 miles in metres
                    fillColor: '#AA0000',
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5 
                   });

                circle.bindTo('center', marker2, 'position');



        }    else {

                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

            }
        })

        looper = looper + 2;
        looper2 = looper2 + 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing the infamous Javascript Loop problem. Javascipt scope is function level, not block level, which can get confusing: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/. Basically, the line:

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) {
```

is getting set with the last item in the array for each geocode, and what you need to do is wrap the first parameter in a closure:

```
geocoder.geocode( (function () { return {'address': sAddress} })(), function(results, status) {
```

The marker and circle are fine, because they are defined inside of a function.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get the idea, and I've changed it. But it's still not working... do I need to pass sName along somewhere to make it available?